# ImageResizer stripping metadata from source file

Tags: iis-8, imageresizer

I have created a plugin for ImageResizer that preserves metadata (xmp, iptc exif etc) for jpeg images.

I used the code at [here](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/tree/master/Plugins/CopyMetadata) as a template and rewrote the ProcessFinalBitmap to copy the metadata from the sourceBitmap to the destinationBitmap in the ImageState.

This worked great locally, on a windows 7 machine using IIS express as well as on Windows 7 with IIS 7.5. But when it is deployed to a real server running Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8 it stops working.

After some debugging I found that ImageState's sourceBitmap no longer has any metadata in it, like it is getting stripped out further up the pipe.

Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Comment: What does the diagnostics page show?

Comment: There are 2 warnings. One because we haven't licensed the Cach plugin yet (we are still testing), and the other is the bitness warning because we are deploying 32bit apps. Here is a pastebin of the server : http://pastebin.com/0E9yLkEq and here is the local http://pastebin.com/B94LJwdm.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist I also noticed that the referenced assemblies are not consistent across the board.  For instance, the server seems to have more references than the local machine, although I am not to sure how that could happen. Also Sometimes the file numbers or info numbers are different, although all the Assembly version number are the same.

Comment: Have you tried the official CopyMetadata plugin?

Comment: @ComputerLinguist Yes, but it drops XMP and IPTC. Here is the metatdata [before](http://pastebin.com/6bLwtNDt) and [after](http://pastebin.com/kfkc7Jen) using this [utility](http://regex.info/exif.cgi) which are a requirment. The truly baffling part as mention in the original post is that the metadata is not reaching the plugin when deployed to a windows 2012 server running IIS 8. I can not think of what in environment could cause this.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist I have also tested the official plugin on a new Azure install of Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8 and it is dropping all metadata as well.

Comment: Windows Server 2012 and higher have swapped out the image codecs, which could affect metadata parsing. We've got a better alternative for parsing  now - https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet, but when writing images we're still stuck with the windows API.

Comment: Example source images would help, as this kind of problem is very image-specific.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist I have example images, but I can not put them in a public domain. If you have a way I can send them privately, I would be happy to pass them along.

Comment: I can only create regression tests for public domain images, sorry! [We do have private support options](http://imageresizing.net/support/contracts) that cover private data/code, though.

Comment: I am actually no longer with the company that was having this issue. I offered to send the image in case it would help with your development efforts. If examining it is not beneficial in any way, then no prob! If there is any other feedback i can provide that will help, let me know! BTW I think you have a great product, and I'm now setting it for my new employer!